# How to set pdf version of existing PDF in IText 7?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

How can I change the pdf version of an existing PDF Document in IText 7?

Only the `WriterProperties` object has the `setPdfVersion(version)` function. But how do I use this on my `PdfReader` document, or on the `PdfDocument`? I am using Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok what you have to do is:

```
WriterProperties wp = new WriterProperties();
wp.setPdfVersion(PdfVersion.PDF_1_X);//X needs to be replaces for the version you want
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("orig.pdf"), new PdfWriter("dest.pdf", wp));
pdfDoc.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the PDF version using setPdfVersion does not conform the new PDF to the set PDF level specified. For example, if you start with a PDF version 1.7, set the PDF version to 1.4 and the PDF has layers; the resulting PDF will still have layers and not meet the 1.4 specification.